# How to determine the presence of different noises in text data while performing Text Pre-processing with millions of rows?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-analysis

Is there any way to determine different kind of noises present in the data or we just assume all standard noises to be present and do a pre-processing considering them. From noises here, I mean, html, mentions, etc

Comment: if by "noise", you mean features that may be irrelevant to your machine learning problem, then yes, most data is "noisy". Noise notwithstanding, standard "bag of words" or "TFIDF" approaches tend to do well despite the noise.

Comment: please provide more insight into how your data is structured

Comment: I want to ask whether we can visualize the data to catch the noises present in it.